# Why does the ubuntu 20.04 update fail me?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, ppa

```
ubuntu# sudo apt update
Obj:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                  
Obj:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease             
Obj:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease         
Obj:4 http://sv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                    
Obj:5 http://sv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease            
Obj:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal InRelease
Obj:7 http://sv.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease          
Obj:8 http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal InRelease             
Err:9 http://deb.i2p2.no unstable InRelease     
Could not connect to deb.i2p2.no:80 (193.150.121.17), connection time expired
Err: 10 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease
   Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com:80 (13.66.3.153), connection time expired
Reading package list ... Done
Creating dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to get http://deb.i2p2.no/dists/unstable/InRelease Could not connect to deb.i2p2.no:80 (193.150.121.17), connection time expired
W: Failed to get http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease Could not connect to packages.microsoft.com:80 (13.66.3.153), connection time expired
W: Some index files could not be downloaded, they were skipped, or old ones were used instead.
```

Comment: Ask Ubuntu is an English Only site.  Please post only in english (even if you have to run it through a translation service).  I am running this through Google Translate.

Comment: I don't have an exact answer for you, but the two problems are timeouts to two repositories: connection timeouts to `deb.i2p2.no` and to the Microsoft repositories.  It's possible these are temporary transient issues that will resolve themselves (try running your `apt update` later in a couple hours), or these are issues with your network or a firewall on network interrupting your connection (if this is a corporate system).

Answer (score 0):

That was fixed with the help of Bashing-om in Ubuntu forums https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2387453&p=13749884#post13749884 1.2k

If anyone have the same issue just type:

```sh
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If it’s unsolve at this point, try with:

```sh
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
```

and

```sh
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

If it’s unsolve at this point, try with:

```sh
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
```

If it’s unsolve at this point, try with:

```sh
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | sudo tee /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base > /dev/null
```

**8.8.8.8 is google DNS.**